# Mysql: extract number from string

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, split, substring

Hello I have a column in the table which is serialized:
I want the last number in the array if there is only one number in that array.

**column**

- a:1:{s:7:"general";s:6:"666423";}
- a:1:{s:7:"general";s:5:"36624";}
- a:1:{s:7:"general";s:12:"36628, 36624";}
- a:1:{s:7:"general";s:5:"36601";}
- a:1:{s:7:"general";s:4:"9847";}
- a:1:{s:7:"general";s:3:"444";}
- a:1:{s:7:"general";s:2:"56";}
- a:1:{s:7:"general";s:1:"7";}

**Expected output**
    -

- 666423
- 36624
- null (i do not want to extract if there is more than one number)
- 36601
- 9847
- 444
- 56
- 7

Which string function would be the most efficient in this case?

Comment: Why don't you just unserialize the values?  Storing serialized strings breaks database normalization, so you're bound to have issues if you need to perform database operations with this column.

Comment: Good point. However, this option is not provided by the tech team. 
I in the data team need to work with what is given in the table.

Comment: Consider switch from "serialized" to the more-standard JSON.  Then use json functions that are available in newer versions of mysql/mariadb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the serialized format that always ends the same way and use reverse+locate-function first to get the string and then see if it contains multiple values.

See [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62bd7/1).